# symfony translation set domain

Tags: symfony, translation, symfony5, easyadmin

I want to devide translations into diffrent files, by default the translation domain `messages` is used. Inspired by [easyadmin translations](https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/dashboards.html#translation) I used a helper function to set the domain automatically.

```php
function t(string $message, array $parameters = []): TranslatableMessage
{
    return new TranslatableMessage($message, $parameters, $domain='admin');
}
```

---

When exporting the translations from code, only the domain messages work, but not the domain admin, although it was defined in the helper function:

```bash
php bin/console translation:extract --force --format=yaml --domain=admin en
```

Result: `[WARNING] No translation messages were found.` and the file `admin+intl-icu.en.yaml` was not created.

---

```bash
php bin/console translation:extract --force --format=yaml --domain=messages en
```

Result: translations are exported into `messages+intl-icu.en.yaml`

---

Allthough all translations use the specific domain, it was not found when exporting.
How to define a translation domain for a certain scope, so that translations are exported into the correct domain? Your help is highly appreicated.

Comment: The translation extractor is [a tokenizer looking for specific keywords](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/e1581a0937c7e0c8d8420808ebc60418a63892c4/src/Symfony/Component/Translation/Extractor/PhpExtractor.php#L33): `trans`, `new TranslatableMessage`... It's not executing the code, so the variables aren't resolved as a valid target and besides, it's not even aware of the `t()` function to start with.

Comment: using `new TranslatableMessage('foo, [], 'admin')` for each translation string is not practical, my goal is to declare the domain within a controller only once. This seems not possible, am I right?

Comment: You can set the domain _per template in twig_ by using the [`trans_default_domain`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#trans-default-domain). I don't think it is, at least easily. But if you are willing to put in the work I don't see why not, your question now is "is it worth it"? You could write your custom extractor that [defaults to a different domain](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/e1581a0937c7e0c8d8420808ebc60418a63892c4/src/Symfony/Component/Translation/Extractor/PhpExtractor.php#L268).